Huygens and "Newton's soul"
Did Huygens say that Newton's force was "Newton's Soul"?
Apparently, Huygens was ambivalent about Newton's Principia. He thought Newton's mathematics was good but

Newton’s idea that gravity is an attractive force, Huygens could not
accept. Considering gravity as a universal force, which operates over
empty space, inevitably led to the problem how any force could act at
a distance. But for a mechanical philosopher like Huygens, nothing
could act at a distance. Talking of gravity this way is talking of
occult causes. [1]

I remember reading long time ago a stronger criticism by Huygens of Newton's force. As far as I can remember, Huygens thought that Newton brought back the old scholastic notion of souls (or occult qualities) into rational mechanics. Huygens said that Newton's force was an agent that acted without time passing which meant that force was everywhere at once.
For this reason, Huygens called Newton's force "Newton's Soul" that permeated the whole universe.
Did Huygens say something like this? (Of course, I'm looking for a direct reference. Searching for "Huygens Newton's soul" pulls up a couple of pages but without any scholarly references.)
[1] https://www.jstor.org/stable/531383 Christiaan Huygens and Newton's Theory of Gravitation by H. A. M. Snelders

Do you have a link tying Huygen with Newton's soul? At least a secondary source? You said you got some results by looking for "Huygen Newton's soul"

I have now looked through all of Huygen's outgoing correspondence that mentions Newton, and have not found any reference to "Newton's soul". From what I gather it seems that Huygens hypothesized some sort of ether (he appears to calls it, in Latin, "ambient matter") which affects the transmission of gravitational force. This was a quick perusal of letters mostly written in French (a language I read with much difficulty), so take that assessment with a grain of salt.

Huygen's strongest language I found is calling Newton's principle of attraction "absurd". Letter to Leibniz, Nov. 18, 1690: "Pour ce qui est de la Cause du Reflus que donne Mr. Newton, je ne m'en contente nullement, ni de toutes ses autres Theories qu'il bastit sur son Principe d'attraction, qui me paroit absurde, ainsi que je l'ay desia temoignè dans l'Addition au Discours de la Pesanteur. Et je me suis souvent etonnè, comment il s'est pu donner la peine de faire tant de recherches et de calculs difficiles, qui n'ont pour fondement que ce mesme principe."

@Mauricio I tried a couple different search engines but I can no longer find the reference.

@njuffa Thanks for the comments and also for link to correspondences. That site may be useful. I think this is enough evidence that Huygens did not equate Newton's force with Newton's soul. I wonder if this was said by someone else.

I checked Huygens's publication Discours de la cause de la Pesanteur which is appended to his Traité de la lumière (Leiden: Peter van der Aa 1690) and did not find a reference to anything even remotely resembling "Newton's soul". Huygens expressed strong disagreement with Newton's ideas on gravitation as they could not be explained by mechanical means, but that is pretty much it.

These lecture notes contain some elements similar to those mentioned in the question: '... critics ... attacked what they saw as the weak point in Newton's theory: gravity, the force of attraction. Newton claimed that it acts at a distance .... Action at a distance is a direct violation of the mechanical principle that all motion is by contact. Newton's opponents went so far as to call attraction an "occult quality," ...

... Newton had described space as God's "sensorium," which Leibniz understood to mean "sense organ." This suggests that God's relation to the world is not that of creator but rather of a kind of "world soul" (as Leibniz put it later). '

@njuffa Thanks. I think this may be what I was remembering. I'm reading Leibniz-Clark correspondence https://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/leibniz1715_1.pdf for more information.

Leibniz called gravity "incorporeal and inexplicable virtue" in a 1690 letter to Huygens, and in Nouveaux Essais (1703) wrote that to accept "gravitation of matter towards matter attributed to M. Newton... is, in effect, to return to occult qualities" adding later "so very occult, that ’tis impossible it should ever be clear, tho’ an Angel, or God himself, should undertake to explain it." For more tirades on "asylum for ignorance and laziness" see Appendix A of Koyre's Newtonian Studies. Huygens was more reserved.
